# Disqus won't show up on my site?

Tags: tumblr, disqus

I can't get disqus working on my site. i've copied and pasted the disqus codes, but they're not showing.
this is my site (testing) http://testtttttttttttblog.tumblr.com

this is my code http://pastebin.com/03RftqQ9

as you can see on my site , you can click on 'comments' above my posts, but after that you won't be able to see the disqus plugin.

Comment: 1) No disqus username set in the theme options: `text:Disqus Shortname`. 2) You only need to include **one** call to disqus, not one per post.
3) You can only display a comment count on the index page, not the comments, as it requires the permalink url.

Comment: i've followed the instructions here: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/758168-tumblr-manual-installation-instructions
i tried changing the 'text:disqus shortname' into mine, but no results